# execute refresh google calendar UI after inserting public calendar with GAE

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api, google-gadget

Execute refresh google calendar UI after inserting public calendar with `GAE`.

I create a gadget with `GWT` and `GAE`, using URL to add it in the Google calendar, this app, just add a list of public calendar for the current user connected.

Everithing is ok, except that I it didn't detect that exists a change, and it is necessary use the Refresh option button of the browser to reload the entire page to see the new calendar.

Any one know a way to inform the google calendar, that the current user have new calendar, and it must do the refresh.
Or a way to call the refresh method using JavaScript from the iframe inside of the gadget ?

Thanks any help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in API to do this. However, if you absolutely *must* offer this feature, and can't rely on Calendar refreshing itself, you can force a reload of the entire Calendar page by calling the following within your gadget:

```
window.top.location.href = "https://www.google.com/calendar/render";
```

It's a pretty nasty user experience, so weigh this carefully with other options.